# Can Azure Functions "function runtime" and "general" settings be set via Bicep or with zip upload?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

In the portal for a Functions App, under Configuration there are three sections:

```
ApplicationSettings
Function runtime settings
General settings
```

I'm creating my App resources with a Bicep script, where I set the Application Settings, for example FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = '~4' and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = 'java'.

However I don't see any way to set certain other config options via Bicep, for example the Java Version in General Settings. It just shows up blank in the portal, and if I deploy my code (via zip deploy using "az functionapp deploy") my app doesn't work without Java Version set, and an HTTP trigger times out with a 502.

I can fix the problem with

```
az functionapp config set --java-version='11'...
```

but it's driving me nuts that I can set some settings imperatively in a template but not others. Please tell me there's a template property I'm overlooking, or maybe a way to include those settings in host.json or similar. I looked at the gradle and mvn plugins, and the seem to run a bunch of commands under the covers to set this stuff up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#siteconfig). you would need to set the `javaVersion` property inside the `SiteConfig` block:

```bicep
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  ...
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    ...
    siteConfig: {
      ...
      javaVersion: '11'
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I would suggest you to configure your function app manually from the portal and then click on the `Export template tab`, it will show you the generated ARM and help configuring your bicep file:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how I missed that in the docs.